# python sys.argv in classes name.py [list of integers 2, 4,..], integer

Tags: python, class, command-line-arguments, argv, sys

I wanna pass 2 arguments, one as list [8, 10], and one as integer in terminal.
file MySeq.py

like: MySeq.py [8, 10], 32
How would i do this?

```
import sys

class MySeq():
def __init__(self, positions, length):
    self.positions = positions  
    self.length = length


def length_fragments(self):
    diffs = []

    diffs.append(self.positions[0])
    for i in range(1, len(self.positions)):
        diffs.append((self.positions[i] - self.positions[i - 1]))
    diffs.append(self.length - self.positions[len(self.positions) - 1])

    return diffs

#positons = sys.argv[1].replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').replace(',', ' ').split()
#positions = [int(i) for i in a]
#length = int(sys.argv[2])
print(MySeq(positions, length).length_fragments())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way will be to pass arguments like this:

```
$ python filename.py 30 50 13
```

And code like this:

```py
import sys
int_arg = int(sys.argv[-1])
list_from_args = list(sys.argv[1:-1])
for i in range(len(list_from_args)):
    list_from_args[i] = int(list_from_args[i])
```

This would mean that the args `30 50` will be converted into a python list object (that contains int) and the last argument ( `13` in this case ) will be treated as a int.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
python MySeq.py 8,10 32
```

Since sys.argv is automatically a list of string, just use comma and split it to become a list.

```
def __init__(self):
        self.positions = sys.argv[1].split(',') # 8,10 to ['8', '10']
        self.length = int(sys.argv[2]) # 32
```

Comment: sorry, its not entirely clear to me how to i would need to edit my code:                                    `class MySeq():`
`def __init__(self):`
`        self.positions = sys.argv[1].split(',') # 8,10 to ['8', '10']`
`        self.length = int(sys.argv[2]) # 32`

Comment: + how would I need to edit my code for a terminal input such as:    `python MySeq.py [8, 10] 32`